# I want to use python3 on sublime-text but I am getting an an error as follows

Tags: python3, sublime-text

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/python3'
```

The following I used in build system.

```
{
 "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python3.6", "-u", "$file"],
 "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
 "selector": "source.python"
}
```

And saved it in Packages User

Comment: The *default* location for the python3 executable is `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: please send a detailed answer to this poblem.

Comment: You need to refer this https://medium.com/@hariyanto.tan95/set-up-sublime-text-3-to-use-python-3-c845b742c720

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that python3.6 default location (if it is installed) is `/usr/bin/python3.6`, just change the path in your build system:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python3.6", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Also, there is a package for sublime text named Python 3, which already contains build system and syntax highlighting for python3. You can install it via Sublime Package Control.